# Designating numeric variables as factors within lme4

Tags: r, lme4

Is there any way to specify contrast matrices within an `lmer` if the variable in question is not a factor *outside* the lmer? As an example, toy data of a 2 x 4 mixed model with group, a between-subjects factor, and time a within-subjects factor. I am testing the between-group differences in score at level of time, however this is more of a technical question concerning whether it is possible to specify numerical variables as factors within an `lmer` (i.e. while keeping them as numeric outside the `lmer`).

```
set.seed(345)
A0 <- rnorm(4,2,.5)
B0 <- rnorm(4,2+3,.5)
A1 <- rnorm(4,6,.5)
B1 <- rnorm(4,6+2,.5)
A2 <- rnorm(4,10,.5)
B2 <- rnorm(4,10+1,.5)
A3 <- rnorm(4,14,.5)
B3 <- rnorm(4,14+0,.5)
score <- c(A0,B0,A1,B1,A2,B2,A3,B3)
id <- rep(1:8,times = 4, length = 32)
time <- rep(0:3, each = 8, length = 32)
group <- rep(c("A","B"), times =2, each = 4, length = 32)
df <- data.frame(id = id, group = group, time = time,  score = score)
```

Note that the `time` factor, which is a numeric variable, has been included in the model housed within a `factor()` command.

```
summary(lmer(score ~ group*factor(time) + (1|id), data = df))
```

This works fine on its own. However when I specify `contrasts` using the same `factor(time)` syntax:

```
summary(lmer(score ~ group*factor(time) + (1|id), data = df, contrasts = list(factor(time) = contr.helmert(4), group = contr.helmert(2))))
```

I get the error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "summary(lmer(score ~ group*factor(time) + (1|id), data = df, contrasts = list(factor(time) ="
```

...which I assume is down to my specifying the contrast matrices for the `time` variable within a `factor()` command.

And if I do not call `time` a factor in the `contrasts =` call...

```
summary(lmer(score ~ group*factor(time) + (1|id), data = df, contrasts = list(time = contr.helmert(4), group = contr.helmert(2))))
```

it returns a result but ignores that factor, with the warning messages....

```
1: In model.matrix.default(fixedform, fr, contrasts) :
  variable 'time' is absent, its contrast will be ignored
2: In model.matrix.default(fixedform, fr, contrasts) :
  variable 'time' is absent, its contrast will be ignored
3: In model.matrix.default(fixedform, fr, contrasts) :
  variable 'time' is absent, its contrast will be ignored
4: In model.matrix.default(fixedform, fr, contrasts) :
  variable 'time' is absent, its contrast will be ignored
5: In model.matrix.default(fixedform, fr, contrasts) :
  variable 'time' is absent, its contrast will be ignored
6: In model.matrix.default(fixedform, fr, contrasts) :
  variable 'time' is absent, its contrast will be ignored
7: In model.matrix.default(fixedform, fr, contrasts) :
  variable 'time' is absent, its contrast will be ignored
8: In model.matrix.default(fixedform, fr, contrasts) :
  variable 'time' is absent, its contrast will be ignored
9: In model.matrix.default(fixedform, fr, contrasts) :
  variable 'time' is absent, its contrast will be ignored
10: In model.matrix.default(fixedform, fr, contrasts) :
  variable 'time' is absent, its contrast will be ignored
```

I am aware that I am violating the syntax of `lme4` here but I am trying to demonstrate what I would *like* to achieve, while acknowledging that I am ignorant of how to do so or if what I would like to do is even possible.

Comment: Post the FULL text of your errors. And you _really_ should describe the hypothesis you are attempting to test. Seems possible that your model specification is faulty.  (I first get an error that implies a syntax error, so search for missing parenthesis.) After fixing the missing paren, a second error relates to the construction: `factor(time) =`.) Voting to close as two typos.

Comment: @42 these are not typos. i am trying to demonstrate what I tried to do in the hopes that there is some solution I am not aware of. I have edited the original post as per your suggestions.

Comment: OK. Removed close vote. Next question. Have you tried modifying the variables to factors and adding the contrasts to the variable before the model call?

Comment: That is the way i usually do it, however i have ten imputed datasets on which i need to perform a regression and the imputation procedure required only numeric variables as predictors. I can transform the predictors to factors for each of the ten imputed datasets, run ten regressions, then calculate coefficients manually using rubin's rules, or i could run a single regression on all ten simulataneously and pool the results using `pool()` in mice. I would prefer the latter option. That's why i need to know if you can factorize *within* `lmer`